# How to use Squid proxy as Cascading proxy in windows 7?

Tags: proxy, squid

I am new to Squid proxy, i was able to configure squid in my windows 7 and work as proxy server to talk to outside world. Now i wanted to try to use squid as cascading proxy. and use fiddler to talk to out side world. Have anyone tried this before? Any help will be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution we just need to change "cache_peer 127.0.0.1 parent 8888 0 proxy-only default" to what ever port and ip we want to forward to. and i worked like a charm